# HTML5Blank WordPress Theme not reading style.css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

---

**UPDATE**:

This is the site: http://espavel.ayinmedia.net/

I got rid of the HTML5Blank theme and upload it again. Added my header and index.php BUT did not add any styling (for testing purposes) in the style.css file, I left it blank. Reloaded the site and it was showing all the styling. It's getting it from that style.css?ver=1.0 that I don't know where it lives.

This is frustrating since I cannot upload my css changes into my WP site.

---

Initially, I was having issues with the theme not reading the media queries, so, I tried adding a responsive.css file to add all my MQ's, which did not work, so I got rid of that file.

I added this line of code to have the header.php connect with the responsive.css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/responsive.css" />
```

**(which did not work)** and then I got rid of that line and after that, it doesn't read the style.css anymore.

This is my current **header.php** file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400" rel="stylesheet">

        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

        <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
        <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
        <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <script>
        // conditionizr.com
        // configure environment tests
        conditionizr.config({
            assets: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>',
            tests: {}
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <header>
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Where is the `responsive.css` file located on your website? The reason it didn't work is because the file most likely exists within a `/css` folder? This is why it's important to know where you've put the file.

Comment: I got rid of the responsive.css file when I saw it did not fix the issue with the media queries and after that, style.css stopped working.

Comment: try to check your developer tool console see if its returning any 404 errors on the stylesheets loaded.

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo, I did check the console and no 404 errors. The only weird think I noticed is, if you click on sources right next to the console, I see a style.css file and a style.css?ver=1.0... not sure if that could be the issue. However, I don't see that file if I look for it in the server

Comment: is it something like <host>/themes/mytheme/style.css?ver=1.0 ? is so this should be fine if the file does not exist on the theme where wordpress is looking for it try to create it manually.

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo yeah, it's host/wp-content/theme/... and then there are those two, style.css and style.css?ver=1.0

Comment: the added query on the url which is ?ver=1.0 should not be a problem if the file is not existing you should create it from within the themes directory.

Comment: Have you tried removing your own styles loading lines from the header and reverting back to the HTML5blank method of loading the stylesheet via the `html5blank_styles()` function in `functions.php`?

Comment: @Peter, yes! I got rid of this line:
<link rel='stylesheet' id='html5blank-css'  href='http://espavel.ayinmedia.net/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/style.css' media='all' /> -->

and it's still getting the style.css?ver=1.0 from somewhere. I noticed that if I delete entirely all the css from the style.css file, it still shows styling, getting it from that style.css?ver=1.0. Not sure where it is getting the styles from.

Comment: Guys, see my UPDATE above in the question description. This is the site I'm trying to add new css on:
http://espavel.ayinmedia.net/

Comment: not sure, you're editing right theme. or right website theme folder. after deleting the `style.css` file, your theme will be broken, and wordpress will try to deactivate it( if there will be another one ).also, not sure, that you added another css file right. you have 2 `style.css` files in your website: 1. from header without ver='1.0'( you added it ), second is loading by default from wordpress functions. what is your question now? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan, I did not create the ver=1.0 and it is not stored anywhere I can delete it from. I just had the normal style.css file in my website and it just stopped working suddenly.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan and my question now is, I got rid of the entire theme, uploaded it again and pasted all my html code, left the style.css blank and it still showed my old styles. I am not sure where the site is getting the styles from to be honest (actually yes, it's from that ver=1.0). 
How do I get rid of that style.css?ver=1.0 and have my site read the style.css file again??

Comment: `style.css` and `style.css?ver='1.0'` are the same file.can guess, that if everything you doing right, then the only thing, which shows you not empty that file, may be cache

Comment: When a stylesheet is loaded with `wp_register_style()` the 4th argument passes it the version number which is then automatically appended to the URL. Look at the line in `html5blank_styles()` and you will see '1.0': `wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');`. If you replace that with `null` then nothing will be appended. See the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_register_style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought. Clearing the cache fixed the issue. There are two options to do that:

1. Clearing the cache on your browser.
2. Using a plugin on WP to clear it such as WP Super cache.

More info here:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-clear-your-cache-in-wordpress/